# Convert Hex Characters to ASCII Characters using EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code  as shown below that i found on a forum , that will convert ASCII Code to Hexadecimal Characters using a VBA script, is it possible to convert Hex Characters to ASCII Characters ??

The code i have is as follows

```
 Sub AsciiToHex()
 Dim strg As String
 Dim tmp As String

 strg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").value = strg

 tmp = ""
 For i = 1 To Len(strg)
 tmp = tmp & hex((Asc(Mid(strg, i, 1))))
 Next

 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").value = tmp

 End Sub
```

I have tried to to swap the hex((Asc(Mid(strg, i, 1)))) to Asc((hex(Mid(strg, i, 1)))) but that did not work. Any help would be appreciated

Sample Data

Hex Format
48 65 6C 6C 6F

After conversion would be the following

Ascii Format
H e l l o

Comment: Show some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hex To String

```
Function HexToString(InitialString As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(InitialString) Step 2
        HexToString = HexToString & Chr("&H" & (Mid(InitialString, i, 2)))
    Next i
End Function

Function StringToHex(InitialString As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(InitialString)
        StringToHex = StringToHex & Hex(Asc(Mid(InitialString, i, 1)))
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Works like a charm - thanks for all your help in solving this solution :

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Public Function KonvertHex(s As String) As String
    KonvertHex = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        KonvertHex = KonvertHex & Asc(Mid(s, i, 1))
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Need to convert Hex to Ascii , not Ascii to Hex as in the function

Comment: @John  I don't follow, the ***D*** is `hex` and the ***68*** is the ascii for ***D***

Comment: Correct - However I only have the Hex values in a sheet,  that i want to translate into Ascii so some how i need to reverse engineer your Function that works great when i have the Ascii values to convert to Hex. Just need the other way around

Answer (score 1):

This uses the worksheet function `Hex2Dec`.

```
[a1:e1] = [{"48", "65", "6C", "6C", "6F"}]
For Each c In Range("a1:e1")
    c.Offset(1, 0) = Chr(WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(c))
Next c
```

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.hex2dec